# When doing a line side tap, Can ground and neutral be tap before the main panel?

Tags: electrical, solar

[image: Solar line side tap]

The picture shows what I’m asking.

Comment: The tap prior to the main can be done but the ground may need to be routed from the electrode. I have run into this in the past with separately derived systems, it will depend on your inspector. If the tap was after the panel it could be any place on the system but prior to the main panel since it is separately derived it could be considered a parallel path if the ground and neutral are bonded in the inverter. My inspectors would flag it with that configuration. Left as a comment for that reason.

Comment: Please do your best to describe with words what's shown in your picture. Unfortunately, not everyone who uses the internet can see very well and some people use screen readers to overcome this challenge. Screen readers don't OCR images very well/at all, so your post is a complete mystery to these folks.

Comment: I don't see how you're going to pick up safety ground (EGC) from the meter pan.  It doesn't exist yet. Come to it, how does *the meter pan itself* pick up EGC?  Usually via the metal conduit connecting it to the main panel, but that'll be broken if you stick a plastic box and/or plastic conduit there.  Meter pans tend not to have ground lugs.

Comment: Who is your utility, and why are you looking into a line-side tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather the service panel is full, otherwise you'd just backfeed a 2-pole breaker there.

The junction box would have to be absolutely enormous because of the wire bending rules for such large feeder.

So how about killing 2 birds with 1 stone?  You might as well use a load center there instead of the junction box; not least, it comes with all the lugs you need and will provide the ground as well as breaker spaces for the solar and more.  Eliminating the need for all that stuff.  May even be cost-neutral or even cheaper.

For instance, I see plenty of 8-space panels with thru-lugs in the $140 neighborhood. At that point you install the solar breaker *normally* off a $10 breaker... and feed the old main panel off the thru-lugs.  You have also added 6 empty breaker spaces to the house for future needs, and taken care of picking up ground for the solar since this is now the main panel.